# How to enable SSL in docker with nginx hosted in Ubuntu

Tags: apache, nginx, docker, web, playframework

I have a web application that's running inside a docker container. 
It's written in Play Framework. My host is an Ubuntu 16.04 server with apache. Docker application use the nginx server. The port 443 is directed to that container. SSL in my Apache server is turned off. Now when i try visiting my domain with https the browser give the warning which is annoying.

So i got some free certificates from sslforfree.com and used it with the docker application but still the warnings come up. Do i need to use those certificates in the apache server too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Your browser speaks with Apache server trying to establish an SSL communication at first, **then** Apache will try to forward the request to your docker container.

So, indeed, it's only mandatory to secure your Apache instead of the container to have the browser not complaining.